# jquery hide() function

Tags: jquery, hide

I'm trying to create a sliding FAQ menu using jQuery, but I'm getting an error that states the the hide() is null. I've tried it in Chrome and Firefox on Mac and Firefox on Win. Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.hide').hide();

    $('h5').click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
    return false;
});


});
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<a href="#" ><h5 >The Heading </h5></a><br />

<div class="hide">
The content.
</div>
```

I've spent the last three hours pouring over books and tutorials online and everything looks right, but apparently not. :P

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you added a reference to jQuery?

Comment: is it possible that the 'hide' class and the 'hide' action are conflicting.  What happens if you change your class to 'myhide'?

Comment: @amosriva No, this is obvious from the extra brackets at the end of the code

Comment: @NeXXeuS but maybe that's the problem :)

Comment: @NeXXeuS the first closes the click event the second the on document ready, there are no extra brackets this is obvious ;)

Comment: @amosrivera My eyes are burning...with SHAME

Comment: @amosrivera Yes, this is all the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: After Ant published the public URL of the page I can confidently reiterate my claim that there is no problem in the sample code posted by Ant in his original question so thank you whoever down voted me. The problem is that Ant's page is using both prototype and jQuery libraries together. This fact is omitted from the original question. These two libraries are conflicting over $ variable. If you change your code Ant to use the keyword jQuery instead of $ everywhere as

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery('.hide').hide();

     jQuery('.toggler').click(function() {
         jQuery(this).nextAll('.hide:first').slideToggle("slow");
         return false;
     }); });
```

I am confident your code will work. Alternatively you can use the no conflict technique as described on jQuery pages here

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

There is nothing wrong with your code. Can you put this on a public site and share the URL? The only thing I can think of is that jQuery is not being pulled in.

Try moving the

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

in the HEAD tag

and the rest of the javascript code after the closing

```
 </HTML>
```

tag

Comment: Did you actually test his code to see if it worked? If you did, I think you would have found that the problem wasn't quite *that* trivial.

Comment: I did create a JSFiddle using the exact code given here. It ran perfectly well without any errors.The original question was about hide() being NULL and nothing else. Why dont you create a JS Fiddle yourself and try it out? I did ask him to put his code on a site so we can see exactly what's going on. Quick with the gun on the downward vote arent you?

Comment: The page that it is on is http://www.messiah.edu/offices/_hr/applicants/applying.html

Comment: I feel so much like the guy who can say "I told you so". The sample that you have given us in the original problem will always work Ant. The problem is NOT in your code as I originally claimed. I am editing my original answer now to explain what is going on.

Comment: works like a charm now! I didn't realize the prototype was in there (too many fingers in the cookie jar....) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Your [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) handler is on the `<h5>` element, from there it's trying to hide the [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) **sibling** element...there aren't any of those.

Instead of this:

```
$(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
```

You'd need something like [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) (that searches all following siblings) on the `<a>`:

```
$(this).parent().nextAll('.hide:first').slideToggle("slow");
```

[You can try it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/36596/).

---

Alternatively, maybe a bit cleaner, you can add a class to the anchor to simplify things, like this:

```
<a class="toggler" href="#"><h5>The Heading </h5></a><br />

<div class="hide">
The content.
</div>
```

Then, since you're on the `<a>`, you don't need the [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) call, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hide').hide();

    $('.toggler').click(function() {
        $(this).nextAll('.hide:first').slideToggle("slow");
        return false;
    });
});
```

[You can try that version out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/36596/1/).

Comment: I don't think that the script gets to the click(). It looks like the browser has issue with the hide() and says "I give up..."

Comment: @Ant - Do you have prototype included on the page as well (in addition to jQuery)?

Comment: yeah, that turned out to be the problem. had to switch the $ with the word jQuery, and it works fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have whipped up a small, simple example of how to do this ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/dztC9/)). I think this may be a little cleaner than your current method. I never liked using `<a>` as the header.

**HTML**

```
<div class="accItem">
    <div class="togHead">Heading1</div>
    <div class="togContent">The content1</div>
</div>

<div class="accItem">
    <div class="togHead">Heading3</div>
    <div class="togContent">The content3</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.togContent:first').slideDown();
$('.togHead').click(function(){
    var item = $(this).parent().find('.togContent');
    if (! $(item).is(':visible')){
        $('.togContent').slideUp();
        $(item).slideDown("fast");
    }            
});
```

**CSS**

```
.togHead{
    width:300px;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:20;
    font-weight:bold;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.togContent{
    display:none;
    width:300px;
    background:#ff0;    
}
```

Comment: There's no need for all that traversing...you can just do `.siblings('.togContent')` for example, also in your example `item` is already a jQuery object, no need to clone it :)